# how to display ModelPopupextender to content page from master page

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and C# and have one doubt.

I have one link button in master page and I have one modalpopupextender in my content page.
I need When I click that button the modal popup window will open in the content page..
Can anyone help, it's very useful for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and markup on the master page:

```
function showClientPopUp() {
        var extender = $get("popupExtenderBehaviorID");
        if (extender !== null) {
            extender.show();
        }
    }

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="showClientPopUp(); return false;" Text="Show PopUp"/>
```